# How can this stored procedure cause a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that gets called by multiple mysql connections simultaneously.

After a month of no errors, last night I got several errors with the message:

"deadlock found when trying to get lock try restarting transaction"

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pull_updates(IN table_name VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN  

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates_to_process AS 
select * from export_progress where tablename = table_name and
progress_message = "imdb_to_mysql_success" and cs_sd_date not  
in (select cs_sd_date from export_progress where tablename = 
table_name and progress_message = "mysql_to_domo_success"); 

insert into export_progress(tablename, cs_sd_date, ts, progress_message) 
select table_name, cs_sd_date, now(), "mysql_to_domo_success" from dates_to_process;

SET @t1 = CONCAT('select t1.* from ', table_name,' t1 join dates_to_process t2 
on t1.cs_sd >= t2.cs_sd_date and t1.cs_sd < (t2.cs_sd_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)' );
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS dates_to_process;

END
```

I'm running it on an AWS RDS mysql instance
Server version: 5.6.29-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I can't see why this would deadlock.

It

- 1) creates a temporary table (which is scoped to a connection if I
  understand correctly)
- 2) writes a few rows into it selected from
  table export_progress
- 3) writes some rows INTO export_progress
- 4)
  returns some rows from a table, joined to the temporary table
- 5)
  deletes the temporary table

I can't see the potential for deadlock here, but I must be missing something because I am getting one!

Thanks for you help!

EDIT 1: Have deadlock message, thanks to comment from @fancyPants :

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2017-08-25 04:58:12 2ba1acaf7700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1643978, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 38 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 5242 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 125547, OS thread handle 0x2ba26ea85700, query id 3210748  domo Sending data
insert into export_progress(tablename, cs_sd_date, ts, progress_message) select  NAME_CONST('table_name',_utf8'AUTO_coaching' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'), cs_sd_date, now(), "mysql_to_domo_success" from dates_to_process
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5167 page no 34 n bits 240 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `autouk`.`export_progress` trx id 1643978 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1643980, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
38 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 5242 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 125548, OS thread handle 0x2ba1acaf7700, query id 3210749  domo Sending data
insert into export_progress(tablename, cs_sd_date, ts, progress_message) select  NAME_CONST('table_name',_utf8'AUTO_backend' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'), cs_sd_date, now(), "mysql_to_domo_success" from dates_to_process
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 5167 page no 34 n bits 240 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `autouk`.`export_progress` trx id 1643980 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;

....

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5167 page no 34 n bits 240 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `autouk`.`export_progress` trx id 1643980 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: It would help to see the actual deadlock message. Execute `show engine innodb status\G`, there's a section "latest detected deadlock".

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants Talking with my co-worker, he suspects that the problem is that after the insert, if the select takes a long time over the network, the inserts will remain uncommitted and will continue to lock the table. The fix would be to make sure the stored proc commits the inserts immediately. What do you think?

Comment: You only posted half of the error message. Post everything till `*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (x)`

Comment: It is possible to get a deadlock here. Try to add a pk on your temporary table that fits to your `export_progress`-table. Also check your isolation level, I guess "serializable" could create a deadlock situation. And it can also be a completely different transaction that is locking, so I agree, add the complete deadlock message.

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants . I've added the (I think) relevant bits - bit concerned about confidentiality etc, and rather a lot to edit. I think what was happening was that after the insert comes a select across the network - if this hangs or let's say takes 30 minutes, lots of other connections will also be doing inserts and waiting on locks etc, and presumably mysql gives up and terminates the transaction. I've hopefully fixed by wrapping the insert in a start transaction; commit; so that it doesn't get delayed by the select across the internet. Thanks for your help!